# How am I supposed to use app.METHOD in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I'm trying to make a simple "route system", that would handle requests and send them to a certain controller.
The problem is that I can't even handle any route, because I get

> Cannot GET /

error in response.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = require('./routes/routes')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'html')

router.load()

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Waiting on :${port}`)
})
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Route config
const routes = {
  ['/']: {
    controller: 'index',
    method: 'get'
  },
}

// Load routes
const load = () => {
  for (const route in routes) {
    app[routes[route].method](route, (req, res) => {
      // Do something
    })
  }
}

exports.load = load
```

Comment: you cant use a `express name_app` for generate an already done structure for routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use your `router` file in app.js, try that:

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = require('./routes/routes')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.use('/', router);

router.load()

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Waiting on :${port}`)
})
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { res.send({ success: true }); });

module.exports = router;
```

It's useless and unreadeable create an array whit your all your routes.
My suggestion is to try use command by terminal `express my_app` for generate the base structure and try to use it or at least read for see how it's work.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I guess. Default routing seems to be a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be lacking the context for how the routing system works within Express.

As a starting point, please create a project with the below structure, and try creating your own route to ensure you have a grasp on how to utilize them properly.

1. Create a new project folder
2. `cd` into the project folder from within your terminal
3. run `npm init -y`
4. Run `npm i express dotenv`
5. Create a file named `app.js` in the root of your project folder and place the below code inside of it:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '30mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {console.log('Server successfully started')});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('Hello, World!');
});
```

6. Create a new folder named `routes`
7. Create a new file named `test.js` and place it inside of the `routes` folder
8. Place the below code in the `test.js` file.

```js
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('Hello from your custom route!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

9. Go back into your `app.js` file and add the below lines of code to the bottom of the file

```js
const testRoute = require('./routes/test');
app.use('/test', testRoute);
```

10. In your terminal, run `node app.js`
11. Make a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/test` by navigating to it with your browser, or by using a REST client, such as [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

Once you have completed these steps, you should understand the basic concept of Express routing.

You can use the router combined with [Express Middleware](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/13/build-and-understand-express-middleware-through-examples) to re-route your user to the proper controller based on the endpoint they are trying to access / the data they are trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

Please test with this code

```
const express = require('express')  
    const app = express();
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.json({"message": "Welcome! it's working"});
        });
```

The complete code is  here on [Github](https://github.com/Saad-Abbasi/My_NCEAC_FYP/blob/master/src/app/api/project/server.js)

Comment: It works when I put this into app.js but don't when it's in router.js

Comment: Please follow Github example